# Can a get() ever be null after a containsKey() check in a Hashtable?

Tags: java, android-studio, hashtable

I've implemented a Hashtable in an android application which is initially populated in the following way:

```
if(table.containsKey(key)){
    table.get(key).add(item);
}else{
    table.put(key, new ArrayList<Items>());
    table.get(key).add(item);
}
```

(variable names changed slightly)

Android Studio gives a `Method invocation 'add' may produce NullPointerException` warning on on both add methods. My previous (and only) experience of dict-type structures comes from Python and this was never an issue, but for safety's sake I'd like to check: is it actually possible for this to ever throw a NPE?

Cheers

Comment: There is an easier way to do this starting in Android API 26: `table.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<Items>()).add(item)`

Comment: @JoeC that's pretty cool, unfortunately it's not supported in my API level (min is 19, requires 24). Thanks, though, didn't know about that

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that even Android itself is no longer supporting API level 19, so you may want to consider why you are.

Comment: @JoeC that's... a very good point. It's not up to me unfortunately, but it's something I'll be asking my supervisor

Comment: Strange, that you're getting the error for 'add' and not get or put as well. Are you sure you are using a `HashTable`?

Comment: @nullpointer It's 100% a <String, List<Item>> hashtable. Item itself can never be null either- I've just checked and AS even gave me a code redundancy warning in an if statement. I can only assume it's worried about the key becoming null after initialisation, going by the answers I've seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the documentation for [`Hashtable.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#get(java.lang.Object)):

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or `null` if
>   this map contains no mapping for the key.
>
> More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value
>   v such that `(key.equals(k))`, then this method returns v; otherwise it
>   returns null. (There can be at most one such mapping.)

So an NPE will occur in the if branch if one KVP in the Hashtable has null as its value.

`containsKey` and `put` will also throw an NPE if `key` is null, so an NPE could happen in the else branch as well.

Comment: Its still doubtful that, why *'add' may produce NullPointerException*?

Answer (score 2):

The key can be present in the map but the value could be `null` as illustrated below :

```
Map<String, String> hmap = new Hashtable<String, String>();
hmap.put("A", null);

if (hmap.containsKey("A")) {
    hmap.get("A").length(); // this can cause a NPE
}
```

To address this you can use the [**`computeIfAbsent()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

Comment: `table.put(key, null)` <-- That will throw a NullPointerException (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put-K-V-)